# Return filtered array js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array of Objects, each containing Array and Objects, like so:

```
data = [{
    "id": 10022,
    "date": "2017-12-31T03:44:19.963808Z",
    "bought_beats": [{
        "id": 10034,
        "beat": {
            "id": 6334,
            "name": "Glass",
            "producer": {
                "id": 23,
                "display_name": "MadReal",
            }
        },
        "license": {
            "id": 10034,
            "name": "Premium",
        },
    }, {
        "id": 894,
        "beat": {
            "id": 6334,
            "name": "Other Name",
            "producer": {
                "id": 25,
                "display_name": "Other Name",
            }
        },
        "license": {
            "id": 10034,
            "name": "Premium",
        },
    }]
}, {
    "moredata": "stuff"
}]
```

And I need to filter the `bought_beats` property, and only return `beat`, if `beat.producer.id === 23`

This is what I have but it's clearly not working

```
data.forEach(order => {
    return order.bought_beats.filter(item => item.beat.id === producerId)
})
```

===========

Edit1:

Trying this. It "works", but it also removed some properties (id & date) from each order object (which is each index of `data`), so I have objects that only contain the array of "bought_beats"

```
var res = data.map(item => item.bought_beats.filter(item => item.beat.producer.id === 23))
```

========

Edit2

This seems to be 1 solution, it maintains the array and object structure the same, while it removes those unwanted elements from the `bought_beats` array.

```
data.forEach(order => {
    let elementToRemoveIndex = order.bought_beats.findIndex(item => item.beat.producer.id !== 23)
    order.bought_beats.splice(elementToRemoveIndex, 1)
})
```

Thanks @Pac0 for the continuous help

Comment: So `data` is an array of objects? and above is one of the objects from that array? And what is the expected output? You want only objects from this `data` array having `beat.producer.id === 23`?

Comment: There is nowhere to return to in `forEach`

Comment: @palaѕн correct, I just edited my post to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

use **[`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** over data.bought_beats since its an array,

**DEMO**

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 10022,
    "date": "2017-12-31T03:44:19.963808Z",
    "bought_beats": [{
        "id": 10034,
        "beat": {
            "id": 6334,
            "name": "Glass",
            "producer": {
                "id": 23,
                "display_name": "MadReal",
            }
        },
        "license": {
            "id": 10034,
            "name": "Premium",
        },
    }, {
        "id": 894,
        "beat": {
            "id": 6334,
            "name": "Other Name",
            "producer": {
                "id": 25,
                "display_name": "Other Name",
            }
        },
        "license": {
            "id": 10034,
            "name": "Premium",
        },
    }]
}, {
    "moredata": "stuff"
}];

var result = data.find(dat => dat.bought_beats.some(item => item.beat.producer.id === 23));
    
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: Data is actually an Array of Objects, I edited the post to be more clear

Comment: this will work but only for the first index (or when it finds the match, i guess). I won't do it for every index in the array

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should be what you want :

```
// project each object to its bought_beats / beats part
var beatsArrays = data.filter(x => x.bought_beats).map(x => x.bought_beats); 

// flatten the array of arrays of beats into a simple array of beats
var beats = [].concat.apply([],beatsArrays).map(x => x.beat); 

// filter
var relevantBeats = beats.filter(item => item.producer.id === 23); 

// serve with a cherry in a sugar-frost cocktail glass (happy new year ! )
console.log(relevantBeats);
```

Snippet :

```js
   
data = [{ 
    "id": 10022,
    "date": "2017-12-31T03:44:19.963808Z",
    "bought_beats": [{
        "id": 10034,
        "beat": {
            "id": 6334,
            "name": "Glass",
            "producer": {
                "id": 23,
                "display_name": "MadReal",
            }
        },
        "license": {
            "id": 10034,
            "name": "Premium",
        },
    }, {
        "id": 894,
        "beat": {
            "id": 6334,
            "name": "Other Name",
            "producer": {
                "id": 25,
                "display_name": "Other Name",
            }
        },
        "license": {
            "id": 10034,
            "name": "Premium",
        },
    }]
}, {
    "moredata": "stuff"
}];


// project each object to its bought_beats / beats part
var beatsArrays = data.filter(x => x.bought_beats).map(x => x.bought_beats); 

// flatten the array of arrays of beats into a simple array of beats
var beats = [].concat.apply([],beatsArrays).map(x => x.beat); 

// filter
var relevantBeats = beats.filter(item => item.producer.id === 23); 

// serve with a cherry in a sugar-frost cocktail glass (happy new year ! )
console.log(relevantBeats);
```

Comment: I get an `item is undefined`

Comment: @Giacomo : do all your original elements of data have a 'bought_beats' property ? Do all your 'bought_beats' have a 'beat' property ? do all your 'beat' have a 'producer' property ?

Comment: yes, they all have those properties, if I log beatsArrays I get an array of undefined indexes

Comment: this is deleting the properties "id", and "date" of the order and also the "bought_beats" property/array is no longer there becuase everything is flatten out :/
This is very hard...

Comment: It's basically doing what `data.map(order => order.bought_beats.filter(item => item.beat.producer.id === 23))` does

Comment: What I'm trying to achive here is to have the same data array with all it's objects and everything the same, I'm only trying to remove from the bought_beats array, those objects that have a producer.id !== 23

Comment: I may have found a solution, I added it on the main question. Not sure how pretty it is code wise.

Comment: oh ok. I misunderstood, as some others have too. I suggest you to give an detailed example of expected output data next time you post a question, it will help you have clearer and quicker answers.

Comment: I see, sorry about that I was super confused myself @Pac0

Answer (score 0):

```
// for each order
data.forEach(order => {
    // we loop thorugh the bought beats array
    order.bought_beats.forEach((item, index) => {
        // and if there's a beat from another producer, we remove it
        if (item.beat.producer.id !== producerId) order.bought_beats.splice(index, 1)
    })
})
```